# Jackson Convert Object to String, property type is Integer, and getter return int, when property is null ,then throws null point exception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jackson, integer

I want convert Object to readable String , so I use Jackson to convert

```
public static class Test1{
    private String testStr;
    private Integer testInt;

    public String getTestStr() {
        return testStr;
    }

    public void setTestStr(String testStr) {
        this.testStr = testStr;
    }

    public int getTestInt() {
        return testInt;
    }

    public void setTestInt(int testInt) {
        this.testInt = testInt;
    }
}

public static ObjectWriter getWriter(){
    return new ObjectMapper()
            .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
            .writer();
}

@Test
public void testJackson(){
    Test1 test = new Test1();
    test.setTestStr("3333");

    try{
        String str = getWriter().writeValueAsString(test);
        System.out.println(str);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e){
        log.warn("JsonUtil object to Str parse json error",e);
    }

}
```

when i run testJackson, throws NullPointException

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.sino.test.order.OrderTest$Test1["testInt"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:390)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:349)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:316)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:778)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1514)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._writeValueAndClose(ObjectWriter.java:1215)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(ObjectWriter.java:1085). Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.sino.test.order.OrderTest$Test1.getTestInt(OrderTest.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:689)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
```

if the entity return Integer, run test ok, but the entity is not created by me ,i can not edit the entity. And the entity not implements Serializable, so i want to know how to convert this object to string ?

Comment: `private Integer testInt;` and `int getTestInt()` don't work well together. If `testInt` is `null` the getter will throw a NPE whether you're using Jackson or not. This is due to `int` not being able to express the value `null` - what should this be anyway? Simplest solution would be to change to `Integer getTestInt()` or adding something like `return testInt != null ? testInt : 0;`.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  sdk return object like Test1. i want to record this as string.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution.

not use jackson and fasterjson ,but Gson

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create();
        String json = gson.toJson(test);
```

Comment: Both Jackson and Gson should have the same problem with the NPE if you didn't change your code. If Gson doesn't run into this then it's probably bypassing the getter and directly accesses the field. Just be aware of that.